# pass ID from jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

HTML

```
<a href="#modal" id="a1" class="leftPanel">Link1</a>
<a href="#modal" id="a3" class="leftPanel">Link1</a>
<a href="#modal" id="a4" class="leftPanel">Link1</a>
```

jquery

```
function mainFunction() {

    $(".leftPanel").click(function () {
        $(".leftPanel").pageslide({
            direction: "right",
            modal: true
        });
        var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
        var linkId2 = (linkId.substring(1, linkId.length));
        console.log(linkId);
        console.log(linkId2);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'my.php',
            data: linkId2,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

And my PHP

```
<?php
   $pageid = $_GET['linkId2'];
   print_r($_GET);
?>
```

So this is my code but it seems not working..Had looked around dint found anything that can help.
Explain the script
I want to take ID of a link and assign it to $pageid
The console.log(data); Saying Access Denied
print_r($_GET); Saying array();
If any suggestion with code.
If need more details please ask I will explain everything that I can.
Will appreciate any help. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an error in your [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. You missed to pass an identifier for the data. Use this:

```
data: {"linkId2" : linkId2},
```

Comment: hek2mgl didnt worked(((

Comment: what gives you `print_r($_GET);` ?

Comment: array(); still
and Console logs still gives access denied

Comment: What if you open `my.php?linkId2=666` in browser?

Comment: From Console.Log
`a137 
137 
Access Denied.`
From print_r
`Array ( )`

Comment: No page could be found at this address.

Comment: Try to think a bit for yourself when checking the address in browser. Otherwise I cannot help

Comment: Yeap)) It is not getting the my.php... How I understand.

Comment: Type the full link to my.php?linkId=666 (I can't know it, you must know it)

Comment: Access Denied. Showing me this.

Comment: try `data: {linkId2 : linkId2},`

Comment: @uross That's wrong, or at least will not help.. Note that the json standrad requires identifiers to be enclosed in `"` double quotes

Comment: @Froxz. So you have the problem. You are not logged in

Comment: Quote from link in your answer:
`data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: OK Can I create a php file just for this so user can access it?
And if Yes how I pass to that page ID that I got.

Comment: Ok I will try but still I need the shown data on my.php 
or in my.php I write the $pageid that I got on second.php??

Comment: On my.php I have
 `<div id="modal">
    <?php
   $pageid = $_GET['linkId2'];
   print_r($_GET);
   $pl_block = BlockType::getByHandle('page_list');
   $pl_block->controller->cParentID = $pageid; // page ID of parent
?></div>`
And If I will create a second.php and try this
`$pageid = $_GET['linkId2'];
   print_r($_GET);`
After in my.php how ca i Assign the taken ID here
`$pl_block->controller->cParentID = $pageid; // page ID of parent`

Comment: Sorry, Froxz. This is too much for stackoverflow. Cannot fix your whole application (and not willing to). Don't take it personal. Try to separate the problem the a couple of easy to understand questions and ask them here. If you solved them all, then you'll see that `{"linkID2" : linkId2}` is the solution